# Spark "sum" command gives Method sum([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, sum, aggregate-functions

Am I going crazy?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
sum([2,3,2])
```

Gives:

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method sum([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```

How can I just get a simple sum?

What is happening behind the scenes with spark to make things so difficult?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`, you are overwriting the sum function from python standard library with the sum function from `pyspark.sql.functions` module. To avoid the overwriting, you can either import the module:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

and refer to the two sum functions as `f.sum` and `sum`.

Or give an alias to the sum function from `pyspark`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as fsum
```

So that you don't introduce two sum functions into the same scope.

Comment: import psypark.sql.functions as f


Your Answer has a typo on that line (psypark). Please correct and delete this comment.